# App crashes at Start by only one user

Tags: iphone, crash, crash-reports, unrecognized-selector

I trying to figure out why my App crashes right after the start on a users iphone 3GS. He seams to be the only one who has this problems. Everbody else can use it. His iPhone is jailbreaked. My App is from the AppStore. I also uses the SafeMode: no change.

He sent me a crashlog and a Syslog:

```
Incident Identifier: [censored]
CrashReporter Key:   6e41ab4ae027f7c34965f94ceb0685ce5e6e4f26
Hardware Model:      iPhone2,1
Process:         [the APP] [2298]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/B1274C37-4CE0-42E2-97B3-7425032F824E/[the APP].app/[the APP]
Identifier:      [the APP]
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  crunchy [1]

Date/Time:       2012-05-05 00:19:38.590 +0200
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.3.3 (8J2)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x345d0a1c 0x345bf000 + 72220
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33fbe3b4 0x33f8b000 + 209844
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33fb6bf8 0x33f8b000 + 179192
3   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x33d15a64 0x33cd1000 + 281188
4   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x340ce06c 0x340c8000 + 24684
5   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x33d13e36 0x33cd1000 + 273974
6   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x33d13e8a 0x33cd1000 + 274058
7   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x33d13f5a 0x33cd1000 + 274266
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x340ccc84 0x340c8000 + 19588
9   CoreFoundation                  0x33c8d1b8 0x33beb000 + 663992
10  CoreFoundation                  0x33c8c642 0x33beb000 + 661058
11  CoreFoundation                  0x33c03178 0x33beb000 + 98680
12  [the APP]                            0x00057eb4 0x1000 + 356020
13  [the APP]                            0x00005f82 0x1000 + 20354
14  UIKit                           0x3374781a 0x33712000 + 219162
15  UIKit                           0x33741b5e 0x33712000 + 195422
16  UIKit                           0x337167d0 0x33712000 + 18384
17  UIKit                           0x3371620e 0x33712000 + 16910
18  UIKit                           0x33715c4c 0x33712000 + 15436
19  GraphicsServices                0x3475ce70 0x34758000 + 20080
20  CoreFoundation                  0x33c60a90 0x33beb000 + 481936
21  CoreFoundation                  0x33c62838 0x33beb000 + 489528
22  CoreFoundation                  0x33c63606 0x33beb000 + 493062
23  CoreFoundation                  0x33bf3ebc 0x33beb000 + 36540
24  CoreFoundation                  0x33bf3dc4 0x33beb000 + 36292
25  UIKit                           0x33740d42 0x33712000 + 191810
26  UIKit                           0x3373e800 0x33712000 + 182272
27  ZFirewall.dylib                 0x00295c56 0x286000 + 64598
28  [the APP]                            0x00005be2 0x1000 + 19426
29  [the APP]                            0x000021e8 0x1000 + 4584

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x345d13ec 0x345bf000 + 74732
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33fbf6d8 0x33f8b000 + 214744
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33fbfbbc 0x33f8b000 + 215996

Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x345d1fbc 0x345bf000 + 77756
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3152e032 0x31528000 + 24626
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3152f03a 0x31528000 + 28730
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x3152e5ea 0x31528000 + 26090
4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33fbf58a 0x33f8b000 + 214410
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33fbfbbc 0x33f8b000 + 215996

Thread 3 name:  WebThread
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x345cec00 0x345bf000 + 64512
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x345ce758 0x345bf000 + 63320
2   CoreFoundation                  0x33c612b8 0x33beb000 + 484024
3   CoreFoundation                  0x33c63562 0x33beb000 + 492898
4   CoreFoundation                  0x33bf3ebc 0x33beb000 + 36540
5   CoreFoundation                  0x33bf3dc4 0x33beb000 + 36292
6   WebCore                         0x3247427e 0x3246e000 + 25214
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33fbe30a 0x33f8b000 + 209674
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33fbfbb4 0x33f8b000 + 215988

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x00000000
    r4: 0x3fb3e48c    r5: 0x00000006      r6: 0x0014b9cc      r7: 0x2fdfdfe0
    r8: 0x00085e30    r9: 0x00000065     r10: 0x001494c0     r11: 0x00000000
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x2fdfdfd4      lr: 0x33fbe3bb      pc: 0x345d0a1c
  cpsr: 0x00000010

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -    0x71fff +[the APP] armv7  <69c79b4476773f6e96ce973ef3cfd3d3> /var/mobile/Applications/B1274C37-4CE0-42E2-97B3-7425032F824E/[the APP].app/[the APP]
   0x91000 -    0x91fff +MobileSubstrate.dylib armv6  <b8a484a95b5d30c5ab59f25362558e7c> /Library/MobileSubstrate/MobileSubstrate.dylib
   0xc8000 -    0xc9fff +SubstrateLoader.dylib armv6  <885b4713fd433c3996edfc3552109041> /Library/Frameworks/CydiaSubstrate.framework/Libraries/SubstrateLoader.dylib
  0x20c000 -   0x218fff +Activator.dylib armv6  <22da11ddbca43147a9a7880a0e78c88b> /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/Activator.dylib
  0x220000 -   0x25cfff +AdBlocker.dylib armv6  <07089bfdb5563a33bee5fc772477dd33> /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/AdBlocker.dylib
  0x26e000 -   0x271fff  libsubstrate.dylib armv6  <65a35eed390832b08134c3cedc6eafa2> /usr/lib/libsubstrate.dylib
  0x275000 -   0x27bfff +Backgrounder.dylib arm  <65349321d416233df984e6b6c5d32373> /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/Backgrounder.dylib
  0x27f000 -   0x280fff +UAFaker.dylib armv6  <c39694ae4d403293afda4fb2fa5d404e> /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/UAFaker.dylib
  0x283000 -   0x283fff +UDIDFaker.dylib armv6  <b06aea841c97cc65192b03eef252f608> /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/UDIDFaker.dylib
  0x286000 -   0x29bfff +ZFirewall.dylib armv6  <854bdd6749cc331fa1fb9597ad8ca28c> /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/ZFirewall.dylib
  0x2a6000 -   0x2acfff +libstatusbar.dylib armv6  <fe21097b2cb83481a70c9ab877af55e3> /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/libstatusbar.dylib
0x2fe00000 - 0x2fe25fff  dyld armv7  <bb9bfc7d242331d29a79adf7ef7aaa18> /usr/lib/dyld
0x31330000 - 0x3133ffff  Notes armv7  <d9c976ca976e3d029f69febd48f17601> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Notes.framework/Notes
0x31348000 - 0x3137ffff  Security armv7  <6599f42a910b3b31a0e1d98c883d61cb> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x313ae000 - 0x313cefff  AppleAccount armv7  <4e0ac5cf93b338ab8c5f34ba3c5e2ee4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleAccount.framework/AppleAccount
0x313cf000 - 0x313d8fff  CoreVideo armv7  <ea847e6dba2d36b1826b255c73b39539> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x31409000 - 0x31412fff  ITSync armv7  <ba8b48d061903e4096774344448776d0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ITSync.framework/ITSync
0x31413000 - 0x3141ffff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <c68262667ac8397a949ce4e92dfec7db> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x31420000 - 0x31425fff  libnotify.dylib armv7  <9d7198e91de9386a9e5ea43608a66a57> /usr/lib/system/libnotify.dylib
0x3146c000 - 0x3146dfff  libsystem_network.dylib armv7  <39bf0f48bd8539169a77f8f61cdcd4c9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x31528000 - 0x31535fff  libdispatch.dylib armv7  <9a0511ad5ebc3db898f1f49ed1a73d34> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x315fc000 - 0x31615fff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <4825c3e392983aba947eca06555e4480> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x3166c000 - 0x31677fff  libz.1.dylib armv7  <ac706bee36593dc683fd5a96a389d72e> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x31783000 - 0x317d1fff  CoreMotion armv7  <58c353bb7e33361f881da07c72f4cdfb> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion
0x317d2000 - 0x317d8fff  ProtocolBuffer armv7  <f9277ee9b85b3722975ad319a323aca0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x31801000 - 0x31801fff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7  <f47c01d627853b328e088b3fdd08e87d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x31802000 - 0x31861fff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <0b36b2272aa33a8c9aa22d99c89d7189> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x31862000 - 0x31862fff  libdnsinfo.dylib armv7  <21415179ffa03f949fa8cc851c6c31c7> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
0x31970000 - 0x31971fff  libdyld.dylib armv7  <41a7b5e5d9983449ab33affed0f635ad> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x31972000 - 0x319a7fff  AddressBook armv7  <3f2071a77bc134cd82065eef90d4082f> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x319fa000 - 0x31a32fff  IOKit armv7  <80ae313ad69d3363935c88e51a11862d> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x31a36000 - 0x31a38fff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <d55f1553d14831a2a5435ae27ef75ef4> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x31a44000 - 0x31a47fff  CertUI armv7  <9060fe03a4943ef295531feced9a17dd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CertUI.framework/CertUI
0x31a59000 - 0x31a5bfff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <683f321680763e519d61541170ba2133> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x31ba0000 - 0x31ca4fff  JavaScriptCore armv7  <61a94142e2d23dafa2964190dd46e9e3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x31cca000 - 0x31cd0fff  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <14c89b7346433c1f8675f454531f6ca3> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x31cd1000 - 0x31cd6fff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7  <c7cfe523e2d73521abc01587313ef730> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x31cd7000 - 0x31cd7fff  Accelerate armv7  <7d5ad465049136afaa1f0d89aac600bc> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x31d25000 - 0x31dcefff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <5538d3f2c7d83b88b06168488fe6326b> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x320eb000 - 0x32101fff  EAP8021X armv7  <9fefc0ada30435fbb3b51818c74f6cb8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x3210e000 - 0x32111fff  CaptiveNetwork armv7  <fc834fd33a18341ea7506587ad895703> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x321a7000 - 0x321abfff  libcache.dylib armv7  <d2f7fd2a352b3cd59c564be34b53cf80> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x321ac000 - 0x321b3fff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <0a082e1d475432959ba93aa3dbf7fb31> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x3221a000 - 0x32261fff  MessageUI armv7  <35a81f5d4eb03467a1447db80337e570> /System/Library/Frameworks/MessageUI.framework/MessageUI
0x32262000 - 0x3228bfff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <57fef84bdc17301d8bf53ba0fb967fe6> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x3228f000 - 0x322befff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <1d73b8a159363f96bb9c039655c5eae6> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x322bf000 - 0x322f2fff  AppSupport armv7  <0217468bd9f839229a47910b7816b3d5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x3246e000 - 0x32a79fff  WebCore armv7  <07941e59d0a33f94802c16c76238fddf> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x32ad1000 - 0x32c25fff  AudioToolbox armv7  <6619c8c13f8d328e923e797fa8d0df23> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x32c28000 - 0x32d49fff  CoreGraphics armv7  <65f6c8701b563542820a26b0dfc4f6a4> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x32d4a000 - 0x32d4cfff  MailServices armv7  <74ae0145ef713c6d91fd8f68885b0a61> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MailServices.framework/MailServices
0x32d4d000 - 0x32d4dfff  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7  <42d8aa2a31843a6e8bfff745644a7ba5> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x32d4e000 - 0x32dd8fff  Message armv7  <2cce1aa95a493906bb0227197f9e4b96> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Message.framework/Message
0x32e3a000 - 0x32e41fff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7  <55f29184efcc3046bb833dd72a4487e1> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x32edc000 - 0x33028fff  MediaToolbox armv7  <482b13059e8a329fa5d832baede25103> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x3303f000 - 0x33041fff  CrashReporterSupport armv7  <9e7efa009730322f84bbc5d8bf1ded94> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x33042000 - 0x3304cfff  AccountSettings armv7  <d083fb384dc7311eb6766b9b2d2dd9c8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x33215000 - 0x3331dfff  CoreData armv7  <9843a401dd1d322383e3e40021cc8b95> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x3365f000 - 0x33661fff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7  <a2631ac302f4310dae8367939e16b7c2> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x33662000 - 0x336fffff  AddressBookUI armv7  <e354aeb3d96e30338e90cc3638ffe81b> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x33700000 - 0x33704fff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <a0772a32cd8b3b9194bb0c29807c1c5b> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x33712000 - 0x33a9ffff  UIKit armv7  <c271b78464d93cb7bf28c6e49df293ba> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x33aa2000 - 0x33ae8fff  CoreTelephony armv7  <af7d1e770e5a3ffd8834a57fb5d40557> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x33ae9000 - 0x33b1cfff  QuickLook armv7  <29d2d981d1d6358381f5716ee37314b4> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/QuickLook
0x33b39000 - 0x33b40fff  AggregateDictionary armv7  <ab9777b39e8e3026ad64dc90323cad7e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x33b8c000 - 0x33bc0fff  VideoToolbox armv7  <570c63dc3a273a5a8c9072fd5567f5c1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x33bc1000 - 0x33beafff  ContentIndex armv7  <ecd71782cd833360872b943ecc65d203> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ContentIndex.framework/ContentIndex
0x33beb000 - 0x33cd0fff  CoreFoundation armv7  <a8444f997111304c9571b3ff974b769c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x33cd1000 - 0x33d1bfff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <b2cac408951c3f3c9ba3cf563e54ce81> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x33e79000 - 0x33eb8fff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <33dcf9a403ae3fd5971d6030ada2fcab> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x33f2c000 - 0x33f6efff  CoreAudio armv7  <c972fd5f8e89333ca680b9a33587f896> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x33f8b000 - 0x3400cfff  libsystem_c.dylib armv7  <a7077267b6743ed3bbdd86d4380c75d9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x3400d000 - 0x3402dfff  MobileSync armv7  <4df400c4559435889eccd88db77a110c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSync.framework/MobileSync
0x3402e000 - 0x34033fff  liblaunch.dylib armv7  <f5ccc8234aea3ebd9a88bd37f0fa23ae> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x3406e000 - 0x3407efff  DataAccessExpress armv7  <66d9047da79a31daa887e6d84c42ecb2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x340c8000 - 0x3418cfff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <6b51e76fde9f381bb7b3bc5badbfee3a> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x3419d000 - 0x3420cfff  ProofReader armv7  <6d843c6aecdd37ae84baa40af8ad7e65> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x3420d000 - 0x34220fff  libmis.dylib armv7  <529ea6e3a87230ce9f6cf3285c22429c> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x34229000 - 0x3422cfff  ApplePushService armv7  <015c68c15621348db9f6a012499170e1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService
0x34270000 - 0x3435dfff  libiconv.2.dylib armv7  <f4146ce07e3031ea8a81fa5516fd77d0> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x343a7000 - 0x343e7fff  CoreMedia armv7  <8e0570582ba535bfa74f1f00eef64376> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x343e8000 - 0x34439fff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <8a41cc6a6d9332308bc415d27577fd24> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x3443d000 - 0x34440fff  ActorKit armv7  <f7aa6cdd654231988aafcf448978f450> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ActorKit.framework/ActorKit
0x3445d000 - 0x344a3fff  CoreLocation armv7  <c1924042951e3df98515c7bf36093c1c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x345bf000 - 0x345d6fff  libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7  <a06ec84e53bf32098b63c0caebdb45b6> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x345db000 - 0x34681fff  Celestial armv7  <7fbd02fa664b33babaf0327c320d1491> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x34682000 - 0x34685fff  IOSurface armv7  <ad50e71624583d06b891344d832f9b08> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x34689000 - 0x346e2fff  EventKit armv7  <0d4e597ee229337183e96e921a72e30a> /System/Library/Frameworks/EventKit.framework/EventKit
0x346e3000 - 0x34720fff  CoreText armv7  <fb6a72faec2330c4b2cd33c2e9c59588> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x3474f000 - 0x34757fff  MobileBluetooth armv7  <63f11756c4aa3262b2317ff3b8e2a977> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileBluetooth.framework/MobileBluetooth
0x34758000 - 0x34764fff  GraphicsServices armv7  <ff78a9636e933f0dbd222f8d26209788> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x34768000 - 0x347abfff  ManagedConfiguration armv7  <f790c26852cb3cf298abe56bc9a3940b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x347af000 - 0x347ccfff  libsystem_info.dylib armv7  <48016be86e3f3cd9aeee1c6590e1ac6f> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x348a6000 - 0x348aafff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <e1cbfe599c96369ca4bdb0dd99d3cd9f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x348ab000 - 0x348b4fff  MobileWiFi armv7  <03d98d5cf6383695aa7d8a88da52f410> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x34929000 - 0x34937fff  OpenGLES armv7  <5a76beaeaa013f0cbf16e5cb154598ab> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x34a51000 - 0x34a89fff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7  <ccea634795153164a681f0f311f4461d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x34ae2000 - 0x34b10fff  MIME armv7  <60de1fe0bbb134d788c09f7c34b1caa4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MIME.framework/MIME
0x34b45000 - 0x34c64fff  Foundation armv7  <09ff368178c5321c9715b9c8d491d53f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x34c65000 - 0x34c67fff  MobileInstallation armv7  <94b6d6c5d9883175af26764567528127> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x34c80000 - 0x34c95fff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <e92cfbb83f7b330db19181e797bb3f7b> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x34c96000 - 0x34c9bfff  MobileKeyBag armv7  <8c35c090bc373cb181fc26b961b8dba5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x366ef000 - 0x3670ffff  PrintKit armv7  <e5a01ca9083a36afacc08611a398e2ad> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x36806000 - 0x368b5fff  QuartzCore armv7  <ef9632c9781f3101916b65e9faae1579> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x368c6000 - 0x368f9fff  iCalendar armv7  <34ce1957082f3518b5740ac33cfc92eb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iCalendar.framework/iCalendar
0x36951000 - 0x36961fff  WebBookmarks armv7  <6956561235333e74b8ff316cb2edc93e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebBookmarks.framework/WebBookmarks
0x36962000 - 0x36a21fff  CFNetwork armv7  <b09e0d53de9f3bc8bde494780f3cdd4f> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x36b19000 - 0x36b47fff  DataAccess armv7  <3a2e67aa1d8834b7a8fc2fbb56654b15> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccess.framework/DataAccess
0x36c05000 - 0x36c14fff  MobileDeviceLink armv7  <563a09bcdb2f32369b1e22f53f58273a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDeviceLink.framework/MobileDeviceLink
0x36ce3000 - 0x36ce4fff  libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7  <ccc041df3de73eafb7a59e74cdb1702b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x36d08000 - 0x36d0dfff  libcopyfile.dylib armv7  <e57c2b9054b831d9a37119baaa4947cb> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x36efc000 - 0x36efdfff  libremovefile.dylib armv7  <e8858a499d663e6a9e3c188521273cc1> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x36efe000 - 0x36f0bfff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <0a1e2bb78d5138419ecad8ba0fe42fdd> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x3704f000 - 0x37061fff  PersistentConnection armv7  <659ea9d5b13d3fefb37acff09016a69c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x3709e000 - 0x370d1fff  StoreServices armv7  <d526715648f435c3aac4c42953e76d20> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/StoreServices.framework/StoreServices
0x37154000 - 0x37155fff  DataMigration armv7  <42e9e87a4e0735c3837e27d4f2adcf55> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x371ee000 - 0x37243fff  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <0221caba81a235c5a896a835e2aac047> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x37244000 - 0x37531fff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <b855d60dac01310495453bddfd004f0d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x3753b000 - 0x37577fff  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <9d97699e44ee3651ba4ac37e5adec35b> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x37626000 - 0x376d7fff  WebKit armv7  <eb9a0d69c64b3127b2bffd71641add3b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x37741000 - 0x37742fff  CoreSurface armv7  <7b83cd757da73e6e826693c29296d3fa> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x37859000 - 0x3785cfff  libmacho.dylib armv7  <43311c113a9d3182b7d007129819f029> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x3785d000 - 0x37977fff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <bada0c2725bb31a483d5adf9aaf1f8df> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x37978000 - 0x37978fff  vecLib armv7  <0c60cd0a60f43d2791d36cb357d30e3c> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x379ae000 - 0x37a43fff  ImageIO armv7  <d520e3241d1130e8ac1375ee0f2c1095> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x37a72000 - 0x37ac0fff  GMM armv7  <049361f664eb3f30b0d25cd56ffc1f0f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GMM.framework/GMM
0x37ac1000 - 0x37ae0fff  Bom armv7  <b178e3efb4d733c694bd5a55e57a314f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
```

Syslog:

```
May  5 00:19:31 [customer iphone] syslogd[2296]: --- syslogd restarted ---
May  5 00:19:36 [customer iphone] [the APP][2298]: MS:Notice: Installing: de.creak.[the APP] [[the APP]] (550.58)
May  5 00:19:36 [customer iphone] [the APP][2298]: MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/Activator.dylib
May  5 00:19:36 [customer iphone] [the APP][2298]: MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/AdBlocker.dylib
May  5 00:19:37 [customer iphone] UIKitApplication:de.creak.[the APP][0x5134][2298]: objc[2298]: class `ADManager' not linked into application
May  5 00:19:37 [customer iphone] [the APP][2298]: MS:Warning: nil class argument
May  5 00:19:37 [customer iphone] UIKitApplication:de.creak.[the APP][0x5134][2298]: objc[2298]: class `ADSessionManager' not linked into application
May  5 00:19:37 [customer iphone] [the APP][2298]: MS:Warning: nil class argument
May  5 00:19:37 [customer iphone] UIKitApplication:de.creak.[the APP][0x5134][2298]: objc[2298]: class `ADSession' not linked into application
May  5 00:19:37 [customer iphone] [the APP][2298]: MS:Warning: nil class argument
May  5 00:19:37 [customer iphone] kernel[0]: crunchy[2298] Builtin profile: container (sandbox)
May  5 00:19:37 [customer iphone] kernel[0]: crunchy[2298] Container: /private/var/mobile/Applications/B1274C37-4CE0-42E2-97B3-7425032F824E [69] (sandbox)
May  5 00:19:37 [customer iphone] [the APP][2298]: MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/Backgrounder.dylib
May  5 00:19:37 [customer iphone] [the APP][2298]: MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/ContactPrivacy.dylib
May  5 00:19:37 [customer iphone] [the APP][2298]: MS:Error: dlopen(/Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/ContactPrivacy.dylib, 9): Symbol not found: _ABCGetPersonCountInSourceShowingLinks
May  5 00:19:37 [customer iphone] [the APP][2298]: MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/UAFaker.dylib
May  5 00:19:37 [customer iphone] [the APP][2298]: MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/UDIDFaker.dylib
May  5 00:19:37 [customer iphone] [the APP][2298]: *** udidfaker: Loading UDID Faker into de.creak.[the APP]
May  5 00:19:37 [customer iphone] [the APP][2298]: MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/ZFirewall.dylib
May  5 00:19:37 [customer iphone] [the APP][2298]: MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/libstatusbar.dylib
May  5 00:19:38 [customer iphone] [the APP][2298]: *** Firewall: hooking into de.creak.[the APP]
May  5 00:19:38 [customer iphone] [the APP][2298]: -[UINavigationController didMoveToParentViewController:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1494c0
May  5 00:19:38 [customer iphone] [the APP][2298]: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationController didMoveToParentViewController:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1494c0'
May  5 00:19:38 [customer iphone] UIKitApplication:de.creak.[the APP][0x5134][2298]: terminate called after throwing an instance of '
May  5 00:19:38 [customer iphone] UIKitApplication:de.creak.[the APP][0x5134][2298]: NSException
May  5 00:19:38 [customer iphone] UIKitApplication:de.creak.[the APP][0x5134][2298]: '
May  5 00:19:38 [customer iphone] ReportCrash[2299]: MS:Notice: Installing: (null) [ReportCrash] (550.58)
May  5 00:19:38 [customer iphone] ReportCrash[2299]: MS:Notice: Loading: /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/UDIDFaker.dylib
May  5 00:19:38 [customer iphone] ReportCrash[2299]: *** udidfaker: Loading UDID Faker into (null)
May  5 00:19:38 [customer iphone] ReportCrash[2299]: Formulating crash report for process [the APP][2298]
May  5 00:19:38 [customer iphone] com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:de.creak.[the APP][0x5134][2298]): (UIKitApplication:de.creak.[the APP][0x5134]) Job appears to have crashed: Abort trap: 6
May  5 00:19:39 [customer iphone] ReportCrash[2299]: Saved crashreport to /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/[the APP]_2012-05-05-001938_[customer iphone].plist using uid: 0 gid: 0, synthetic_euid: 501 egid: 0
```

Its seams to crash at:

```
-[UINavigationController didMoveToParentViewController:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1494c0
```

But i have no idea why. Can some one help?

Comment: `didMoveToParentViewController`is available in iOS 5.0 and later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An unrecognized selector is when you try to call a method that doesn't exist. `didMoveToParentViewController:` is only available in IOS 5.0 and higher, and it looks like this user only has version 4.3.3. It might to be best to change the minimum required version to 5.0.